# Intentionally undefine a symbol in a linker script file

Tags: c, linker, ld, ram, rom

I am creating a linker script file for a code to run on RAM. 
To save RAM, I'm trying to reuse code from ROM.
To do this, I'm including the ROM list of symbols with their memory address.

But lets say, that some of the code in the ROM is not coded correctly, and I need a copy of it in the RAM to fix it.

How do I make the linker script file (after it includes the list of symbols), to "delete" a symbol mapping, so the linker will use the symbol from the compiled code?

Comment: Which linker are you using? Different linkers use different languages for their linking scripts.

Comment: I'm using GCC linker for ARM

Comment: Possible related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032598/gnu-ld-how-to-override-a-symbol-value-an-address-defined-by-the-linker-script